# Redirect stdout to client - from server

Tags: c, server, gdb, client, buffer

I have a client and server program where the server is a simple shell.

The client writes a command to the server, the server checks if the command is allowed, and then executes it if it is

The client code goes like...

```
  while(1){
      printf("rrsh> ");
      Fgets(buf, MAXLINE, stdin);
      if ((p3ret_val = p3parseline(buf, argv)) == 1)
        printf("You didn't enter anything\n");
      if (!strcmp(argv[0], "quit"))
        break;
      Rio_writen(clientfd, buf, strlen(buf));
      Rio_readlineb(&rio, buf, MAXLINE);
      if (!strcmp(buf, "Command not allowed\n")){
        strcpy(buf, "Cannot execute '");
        strcat(buf, argv[0]);
        strcat(buf, "' on this server\n");
        Fputs(buf, stdout);
      }
      memset(&buf[0], 0, sizeof(buf)); //flush the buffer
    }
```

The server code goes...

```
while((n = Rio_readlineb(&rio, buf, MAXLINE)) != 0){ //loop until connection has been terminated
  if (n == 0)
    flag1 = 0; //the user will need to login again
  if (flag1 == 1){ //the user is loged in
    printf("server received %zu Byte(s)\n", n);
    bg = p3parseline(buf, argv);
    strcat(argv[0], "\n");

    //check if the command is allowed
    flag2 = 0; //set command allowed? flag back to false
    file = Fopen("rrshcommands.txt", "r");
    while (Fgets(command, MAXLINE, file) != NULL){
      if (!strcmp(argv[0], command)){
        flag2 = 1;
        strcpy(buf, "Command approved\n");
        // break;
      }
    }
    Fclose(file);

    strtok(argv[0], "\n");

    // Fputs(buf, stdout);

    if (flag2 == 0){ //case where the command is not allowed
      strcpy(buf, "Command not allowed\n");
      Rio_writen(connfd, buf, strlen(buf));
    }
    else{
      if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {   /* Child runs user job */
        Dup2(connfd, 1);
        // Close(connfd);
        if (execve(argv[0], argv, environ) < 0) {
          printf("%s: Command not found.", argv[0]);
          exit(0);
        }
      }
      /* Parent waits for foreground job to terminate */
      if (!bg) {
        int status;
        if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) < 0)
          unix_error("waitfg: waitpid error");
      }
    }
    memset(&buf[0], 0, sizeof(buf)); //flush the buffer
  }
}
```

Debugging I have discovered that somehow buf on the client side get's filled with the first file that ls is supposed to display.

It's a weird series of events. I enter the valid /bin/ls command, then after that is supposed to be executed I enter another garbage command. After the second time the client reads from the server it returns what I just said -- that first file that /bin/ls is supposed to display

This is from the client side..

```
rrsh> /bin/ls

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffe5d8) at rrsh-client.c:42
42        Rio_writen(clientfd, buf, strlen(buf));
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
rrsh> wprg

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffe5d8) at rrsh-client.c:42
42        Rio_writen(clientfd, buf, strlen(buf));
(gdb) p buf
$2 = "wprg\n", '\000' <repeats 8186 times>
(gdb) n
43        Rio_readlineb(&rio, buf, MAXLINE);
(gdb) n
44        if (!strcmp(buf, "Command not allowed\n")){
(gdb) p buf
$3 = "csapp.h\n", '\000' <repeats 8183 times>
```

You'll notice I never write from the server to the client except in the case that the command is not allowed

why is the client reading the first filename from the server when I am redirecting stdout -- not writing?

Comment: Isn't "csapp.h" some of the "output" of the "/bin/ls" command run on the server???    One problem your interface may have is a means of detecting "boundries" of transactions... i.e. providing the client a means of detecting the end of output from the command executed by the server.  There are numerous ways to handle that...

Comment: You said   "You'll notice I never write from the server to the client except in the case that the command is not allowed", but when you do `dup2(connfd, 1);`, that means the standard output of the program you subsequently exec will be written to the same network connection as connfd.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick in the server code in the child process

Comment: Correct, the server's child process uses the TCP/IP connection as its STDOUT, which is inherited when /bin/ls is exec'd.  the /bin/ls command runs (on the server) and writes its output (probably several lines) to its STDOUT (which is the TCP/IP connection to the Client).  The Client reads from the TCP/IP (using Rio_readlineb() which hasn't been shown). and "csapp.h\n" is read.  What is the confusion/question....?  Do you think "csapp.h\n" is unexpected????  if so, why???

Comment: @TonyB Shouldn't the output be directly printing without having to execute a read command?

Comment: Think of the connection as a pipe... one end on the server, the other in the client.  The "/bin/ls" command runs on the server, and writes its output in one end of the (TCP/IP) pipe (i.e. its STDOUT), and the client "reads" from the other end of the pipe...  (i.e. read it into "buf" ).  Then the client program can "decide" what to do with what it has just read... write it to its STDOUT, write it to a file, just ignore it, or whatever.